# How to add increase deacrese buttons into woocommerce product loop(shop page)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have added my buttons into woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

```
<button type="button" class=" ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button plus" data-product_id="274">+</button>
<button type="button" class="minus" data-product_id="274">-</button>
```

My plus button is adding product via AJAX but problem is I have not found any solution for my minus button.

So how can I decrease product one by one in woocommerce shop page with AJAX?

Comment: Why reinvent the [wheel](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/)?